# Issue: Chrome 32 developer tools search moved and seems broken (Indexing...)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Recently got updated to Chrome 32 and notice the search has moved into the same area as the emulation and console.

I used to be able to search pretty much anything like resources or elements, but now I type in a string or regex and hit enter and just see Indexing... with loading indicator that never stops along with a stop button that doesn't work.

Anyone else having this and is there a fix or something simple I am missing?

Comment: This just magically started working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Emptying the browser history did the trick for me.

Update:
Seems to be not consistent. Just came up again and clearing history did not work this time.